# Using Bootstrap Grid to align content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, gridview, grid

I used the Bootstrap Grid format so that I would be able to align my images but for some reason it isn't working. they are all in one like to the left as if i had set them as blocks and it won't work if i give their positions as inline-block either. How will I be able to edit it so that my 5 images will have a responsive grid format?

```
<div id="section2" class="container-fluid">
    <h2>The Members</h2>
    <h3 id="hoverovertext">(Hover-over each member to learn more)</h3>
        <div class="row1" width="100%">
            <div class="members col-md-4" id="ohno" height="225px">
                <img src="images/ohno.jpg" class="images" height="225px">
                <span class="text">Satoshi Ohno(Leader)<br>Birth: 26-11-1980, <br>Tokyo (Jpn)<br>Joined "Johnnys" in 1994</span>
            </div>    

            <div class="members col-md-4" id="sakurai" height="225px">
                <img src="images/sakurai.jpg" class="images" height="225px">
                <span class="text">Sho Sakurai<br>Birth: 25-01-1982, <br>Tokyo (Jpn)<br>Joined "Johnnys" in 1995<br>Graduated Keio University</span>
            </div>
        </div>
            <div class="members col-md-4" id="aiba" height="225px">
                <img src="images/aiba.jpg" class="images" height="225px">
                <span class="text">Masaki Aiba<br>Birth: 24-12-1982, <br>Chiba (Jpn)<br>Joined "Johnnys" in 1996</span>
            </div>    
        <div class="row2" width="100%">
            <div class="members col-md-6" id="ninomiya" height="225px">
                <img src="images/ninomiya.jpg" class="images" height="225px">
                <span class="text">Kazunari Ninomiya<br>Birth: 17-06-1983,<br>Tokyo (Jpn)<br>Joined "Johnnys" in 1996</span>
            </div>    

            <div class="members col-md-6" id="matsumoto" height="225px">
                <img src="images/matsumoto.jpg" class="images" height="225px">
                <span class="text">Jun Matsumoto<br>Birth:30-08-1983, <br>Tokyo (Jpn)<br>Joined "Johnnys" in 1996</span>
            </div>    
        </div>
```

Comment: I think one `col-md-4` needs to be inside that `row1`. also make sure that the `width` of the images is `100%`

Comment: I want it so that there are 3 images on the top row and 2 on the bottom but as the screen gets smaller, it becomes like a checker board

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should get you started...

Each horizontal row should be in a `<div class="row">`

Inside a row, all `col` should add up to 12. So, there's a 2+4+4+2 row, and there's also a 6+6 row, etc.

Don't forget `class="img-responsive"` for images... very useful.

```css
.imgIB{display:inline-block !important;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="section2" class="container-fluid">
    <h2>The Members</h2>
    <h3 id="hoverovertext">(Hover-over each member to learn more)</h3>

 <div class="row1" width="100%">
  <div class="col-xs-2"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 members" id="ohno">
   <img src="http://placeimg.com/100/100/animals" class="img-responsive">
   <span class="text">Satoshi Ohno(Leader)<br>Birth: 26-11-1980, <br>Tokyo (Jpn)<br>Joined "Johnnys" in 1994</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 members" id="sakurai">
   <img src="http://placeimg.com/100/100/animals" class="img-responsive">
   <span class="text">Sho Sakurai<br>Birth: 25-01-1982, <br>Tokyo (Jpn)<br>Joined "Johnnys" in 1995<br>Graduated Keio University</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2"></div>
 </div><!-- .row -->

 <div class="row1" width="100%">
  <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 members" id="aiba">
   <img src="http://placeimg.com/100/100/animals" class="img-responsive">
   <span class="text">Masaki Aiba<br>Birth: 24-12-1982, <br>Chiba (Jpn)<br>Joined "Johnnys" in 1996</span>
  </div>    
  <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
 </div><!-- .row -->

 <div class="row" width="100%">
  <div class="col-xs-6 members text-center" id="ninomiya">
   <div>
              <img src="http://placeimg.com/100/100/animals" class="img-responsive imgIB">
            </div>
   <span class="text">Kazunari Ninomiya<br>Birth: 17-06-1983,<br>Tokyo (Jpn)<br>Joined "Johnnys" in 1996</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 members text-center" id="matsumoto">
   <div>
               <img src="http://placeimg.com/100/100/animals" class="img-responsive imgIB">
            </div>
   <span class="text">Jun Matsumoto<br>Birth:30-08-1983, <br>Tokyo (Jpn)<br>Joined "Johnnys" in 1996</span>
  </div>    
 </div><!-- .row -->
</div>
```

Comment: I tried to include the changes but it does not seem to have worked apart from when i included text-center and just move the text alone into the center of the page. Here is my css for the page.

Comment: /*css for the members section of the webpage*/
#section2 {
    padding-top:50px;
    height:775px;
    color: #0000CD;
    background-color: #ADD8E6;
    width:100%;
}
#hoverovertext {
    font-size:16px;
}
.members {
    position: relative;
      padding: 0px 0px 200px 0px;
      width:100%;
}
.images {
    position: absolute;
    padding:20px;
    z-index:1;
}
.images:hover {
    opacity:0.35;
}
.text {
    position: absolute;
    padding:25px;
    width:100%;
}
.imgIB {
    display:inline-block;
}

Comment: You are over-styling. The reason to use Bootstrap is to leverage its styling. When you apply `position:absolute` to images, you undo bootstrap defaults. Bootstrap is designed so that you use as little manual css styling as possible. For styling, add additional Bootstrap classes (like "text-center" etc). Watch more YouTube tuts on Bootstrap. Here's a good source: [codedamn YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCJUmE61LxhbhudzUugHL2wQ)

Comment: Will I be able to use z-index without absolute positioning?

Comment: It also works with `position:relative` -- which shouldn't move the element at all, just makes it work with `top` and `left` and `z-index` etc. (The default is `position:static` which is almost identical to `position:relative`) https://css-tricks.com/what-if-there-was-no-position-static/